# Why am I getting a "plugin conflicts with IDE" error when starting Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-17

I installed a Haskell plugin, and now run into this error when attempting to run Intellij:

[image]

Is this because I am attempting to use the community edition with a non-java plugin, the solution being purchase of the ultimate edition? Why then would it have invited me to install the plugin in the first place?

---

Version of "Haskell" plugin is: 0.5.2

[image]

Version of "IntelliJ-Haskell" plugin is: 1.0.0-beta8

[image]

---

Here are the contents of `idea.log` which arise from attempting to start IntelliJ with these offending plugins enabled.

```
2017-06-15 13:07:11,646 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,673 [     27]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,673 [     27]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 2.0 (JRE-managed HiDPI) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,682 [     36]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-171.4424.56, 12 May 2017 11:11) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,683 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (10.12.5, x86_64) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,683 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,683 [     37]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.112-b21 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,695 [     49]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xverify:none -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/matthewherzl/java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/matthewherzl/java_error_in_idea.hprof -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions -Didea.java.redist=jdk-bundled -Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents -Didea.executable=idea -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2017.1 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,695 [     49]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext: [cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,695 [     49]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /System/Library/Java/Extensions: [AppleScriptEngine.jar, dns_sd.jar, j3daudio.jar, j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar, jai_codec.jar, jai_core.jar, libAppleScriptEngine.jnilib, libJ3D.jnilib, libJ3DAudio.jnilib, libJ3DUtils.jnilib, libmlib_jai.jnilib, mlibwrapper_jai.jar, MRJToolkit.jar, vecmath.jar] 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,696 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: /usr/lib/java: [libjdns_sd.jnilib] 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,696 [     50]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: UTF-8 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,708 [     62]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 12 ms 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,723 [     77]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - initializing environment 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,724 [     78]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/private/var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.tmp' 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,841 [    195]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - shell environment loaded (16 vars) 
2017-06-15 13:07:11,842 [    196]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
2017-06-15 13:07:13,498 [   1852]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,105 [   2459]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 38 plugins initialized in 926 ms 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,107 [   2461]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.2.2.2), Ant Support (1.0), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage (171.4424.56), Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (171.4424.56), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub (171.4424.56), Gradle (171.4424.56), Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java (171.4424.56), IDEA CORE (171.4424.56), IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (171.4424.56), JavaFX (1.0), Kotlin (1.1.2-release-IJ2017.1-1), Maven Integration (171.4424.56), Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support (171.4424.56), Settings Repository (171.4424.56), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer (171.4424.56), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML (171.4424.56), hg4idea (10.0) 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,107 [   2461]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: CHelper (4.1.3), Generate Tests (1.0.2), HaskForce (0.3-beta.37), Haskell (0.5.2), IdeaVim (0.46), IntelliJ-Haskell (1.0.0-beta8) 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,949 [   3303]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=705 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,980 [   3334]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2017-06-15 13:07:14,990 [   3344]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,228 [   3582]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.haskforce.HaskellFileTypeFactory' 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.haskforce.HaskellFileTypeFactory'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:210)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.haskforce.HaskellFileTypeFactory'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:308)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.<init>(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:473)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.haskforce.HaskellFileType.<init>(HaskellFileType.java:13)
    at com.haskforce.HaskellFileType.<clinit>(HaskellFileType.java:10)
    at com.haskforce.HaskellFileTypeFactory.createFileTypes(HaskellFileTypeFactory.java:10)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:305)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.ImplementationConflictException: Language with ID 'Haskell' is already registered: class org.jetbrains.haskell.HaskellLanguage
    at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:87)
    at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:71)
    at com.intellij.lang.Language.<init>(Language.java:67)
    at com.haskforce.HaskellLanguage.<init>(HaskellLanguage.java:20)
    at com.haskforce.HaskellLanguage.<clinit>(HaskellLanguage.java:17)
    ... 42 more
2017-06-15 13:07:15,231 [   3585]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3  Build #IC-171.4424.56 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,232 [   3586]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,232 [   3586]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,232 [   3586]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,232 [   3586]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,457 [   3811]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - action with the ID "Haskell.HaskellFile" was already registered. Action being registered is Haskell Module (Create new Haskell module); Registered action is Haskell Module (Creates new Haskell module) Plugin: IntelliJ-Haskell [Plugin: intellij.haskell] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: action with the ID "Haskell.HaskellFile" was already registered. Action being registered is Haskell Module (Create new Haskell module); Registered action is Haskell Module (Creates new Haskell module) Plugin: IntelliJ-Haskell [Plugin: intellij.haskell]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:361)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerChameleon(ActionManagerImpl.java:1028)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.addToMap(ActionManagerImpl.java:1001)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerOrReplaceActionInner(ActionManagerImpl.java:637)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionsChildElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.WindowManager.getInstance(WindowManager.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.<init>(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerFactoryImpl.createPeer(DialogWrapperPeerFactoryImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.createPeer(DialogWrapper.java:850)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:229)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:225)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:270)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.errordialog.PluginConflictDialog.<init>(PluginConflictDialog.java:59)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginConflictReporter.reportConflictByClasses(PluginConflictReporter.java:56)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.processException(PluginManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processException(IdeEventQueue.java:422)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2017-06-15 13:07:15,458 [   3812]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3  Build #IC-171.4424.56 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,458 [   3812]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,458 [   3812]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,458 [   3812]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,459 [   3813]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,461 [   3815]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - action with the ID "Haskell.ShowType" was already registered. Action being registered is Show Type (Show type of (selected) expression); Registered action is Show Type (Show Type) Plugin: IntelliJ-Haskell [Plugin: intellij.haskell] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: action with the ID "Haskell.ShowType" was already registered. Action being registered is Show Type (Show type of (selected) expression); Registered action is Show Type (Show Type) Plugin: IntelliJ-Haskell [Plugin: intellij.haskell]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:361)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerChameleon(ActionManagerImpl.java:1028)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.addToMap(ActionManagerImpl.java:1001)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerOrReplaceActionInner(ActionManagerImpl.java:637)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processGroupElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:723)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionsChildElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:964)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:128)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:100)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.WindowManager.getInstance(WindowManager.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.<init>(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerFactoryImpl.createPeer(DialogWrapperPeerFactoryImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.createPeer(DialogWrapper.java:850)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:229)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:225)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.<init>(DialogWrapper.java:270)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.errordialog.PluginConflictDialog.<init>(PluginConflictDialog.java:59)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginConflictReporter.reportConflictByClasses(PluginConflictReporter.java:56)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.processException(PluginManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.processException(IdeEventQueue.java:422)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2017-06-15 13:07:15,462 [   3816]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3  Build #IC-171.4424.56 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,462 [   3816]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,462 [   3816]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,463 [   3817]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-06-15 13:07:15,463 [   3817]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X
```

Comment: Which plug-in version did you install? Are there any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: `Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.ImplementationConflictException: Language with ID 'Haskell' is already registered: class org.jetbrains.haskell.HaskellLanguage` ...  Maybe it thinks you accidentally installed it twice?

Comment: Actually yes, you have installed it twice, Jetbrains' Haskell version is already there, and then you installed `intellij-Haskell` on top.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can fix the issue? Perhaps by removing the older version somehow?

Comment: @mherzl I would just remove the `intellij-Haskell` plugin and re-enable the Jetbrains one. You should use the @ to notify me otherwise I won't see your comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by reinstalling the IDE on my local.

Initially I tried removing the plugins from the Applications folder. But that did not help. So I had to reinstall the IDE to fix the conflicting plugins issue.